# Adding a view causes constraints in Storyboard to update

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, constraints

I created a UIScrollView with its constraints set in storyboard, but I sometimes move the UIScrollView to a different position at runtime.

My problem happens when I create a custom UIView programmatically and add it the the main UIView. My constraints will update, and if my UIScrollView is not is the same location, it will be moved to the storyboard setting.

For instance, imagining my UIScrollView is pinned to the top of the screen, and then I move it to the bottom of the screen at runtime. If I execute this code:

```
  let menu = UIView()
  menu.frame.size = CGSize(width: 210, height: 80)
  menu.center = view.center
  view.addSubview(menu)
```

My UIScrollView will moved back to the tap on the screen. I try this but it did not work:

```
  myScrollView.constraints.first?.isActive = false
```

Comment: *"but I sometimes move the UIScrollView to a different position at runtime"* -- how are you doing that? It sounds like you are changing the ***frame*** of the scroll view at runtime, instead of updating its constraints (such as setting the `.constant` value).

Comment: I am moving the frame. I wasn't aware I can move the constraint? I'm new to constraints

Comment: As @DonMag said, when you're using constraints you shouldn't update frame values, instead you should update constraint.constant. You can connect an `@IBOutlet` from the constraint to your code, and then manipulate it in the code. (If you want, you can as well animate it, but animating constraints it's a bit trickier than normal frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using auto-layout and constraints, you cannot change frames by setting the `view.frame` explicitly.

If you try to do so, then on the next UI update auto-layout will reset the view to its constraints.

If you need to move / size a view at run-time, you'll want to have a reference to the constraint(s) you've set, and then modify the constraint.

For example, if your scroll view is constrained 20-pts from the top of the view, and you want to move it down 50-pts at run-time...

- create an `IBOutlet` for the top constraint
- in code, use `myTopConstraint.constant = 70.0`